# How to associate Android app with Google Drive files having particular extension?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, intentfilter

I need to associate files with particular extension from Google Drive (.gpx, for example) with my app. So when I click the .gpx file on Drive, I should have an option to open this file with my application.

Currently I have an activity handling these files clicking declared in AndroidManifest.XML in a way below, and it works for locally stored files and gmail attachments, but not for Drive:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.PhotosActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="ftp"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:host="*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx"
                    android:scheme="file"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx"
                    android:scheme="content"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Then add this to your activity:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
            android:value="id=xxxxxxx" />
```

where xxxxxxx is your Project ID as declared with Google API console.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.1234567890" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx" />
         </intent-filter>
```